# $_SESSION is registering but cleaning after that

Tags: php, session, post, redirect, authentication

I'm using `$_SESSION` to create a login system, it work before but I modified something because now, its not work...

In login.php, I get the values with `$_POST`:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
```

and after, I redirect with a Header( `Header("Location: panel.php");` ) checking if exist some `$_SESSION['id']`:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
```

, when redirect to this page, the value on `$_SESSION` is empty...

I'm not using session_destroy to do that, someone can help me?

PS.: I call session_start() in all page, included panel.php

Comment: Are you remembering to use session_start()?

Comment: You must call `session_start()` at the top of `panel.php` as well as the script that initially sets the session variable.

Comment: I use <?php ob_start(); @session_start; ?> in all pages...

Comment: And when I return to page for login, no have any $_SESSION registered... the $_SESSION exist only in page login.php

Comment: @GtOkAi: First make sure you get the `$_POST['id']`

Answer (score 4):

you have to initialize the session on each php page. with `session_start()`.

define `session_start()` on top of each php page where you want to use session variable. otherwise session variable won't work

Comment: I use <?php ob_start(); @session_start; ?> in all pages...
And when I return to page for login, no have any $_SESSION registered... the $_SESSION exist only in page login.php

Comment: it is not @session_start. correct the function name to `session_start();`

Comment: can you post the code of your `login.php` plus any other php page in which you are trying to access session variable?